# Keep lines between the two > signs, keeping the first one but excluding the subsequent one

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a DNA file like this, where the sequence description is on the line that follows the > sign, the the sequence follows on the next line until the next sequence descriptor, >. I want to extract a specific sequence (sequence description line + sequence) without keeping the next identifier line.

File:

```
>k141_166416 flag=1 multi=2.0000 len=644
AAATAGTAAAACTCCAGAAGATGAATAATAAAAATCAGTCTCTAATATCTCATTTAATTGATCAGAAAAAATATTATTATAATCTAAATTTATTCTAGTATTTTTTAAAAATTGATTACTTAAGTCAAATTTAAAATAATCAACGATAATTCCTTTCTTCTCTTTCAAGTCAAAAGAAAAATCTCTATCAATATACTCTGAAGGATAAATTGTATAAAAATTCACAGACCAACCTTTAAAACATCTTATTTCAAAGTAGTACTTCTAAACAAGCATCTAGAGATACTACTTATTTTTGAATATTACTTACACTTTAACCATAAAAAAATTCTATAAAATACTCTATATCTAACAATACTTTTTCATTTATAAGAATTTTCTTTAACTCTTCTAAAAAACCTGTTTTATACCCTCCATTTTCACCTCTAGGGTTAGAGTCATATAGGTCAATAATTAAATTCTGCACAATATTAATTTGCGAAAAAAATCAAATAAATTTTTAGCAATGATATGTAATTCATCGCCTGAAATACATGCTCCTATCTCGCCACTATTATGATTAATGTATACGACATTTACATCATGCTGTGTTAAGAATACTGTAGTACTTTCCCCATCAAATATATCTTCAAACATATATTGAA
>k141_41604 flag=1 multi=2.0000 len=319
GGGCTCGTAGCCCATGGCCGGCTGCGTCAGGATGCGGCGCAGCTGCGCCATCACGCCCTGTGCTCGCTGGCGCGCGCGCATGAGCGGCCCGGTCAGGGGACCGCCGGCGGGCAGGTACATGCCGCCGCCCATGAATGACGCCGGCTGGCTGACGCGGCTGACCAGCTGCGTCGGCACGAAGCCGGCCTGGCGCGGCGCGCCGCTGTGGGAAAAACCGTAGCCGCTCGCAGGCGACCCCATGGGCCTGGAGGCGGGGCCGAGCGGCCCCGAGAGCGAGCCGGGGCCGGTGCCGTAGGGGCCCGATGCGTCCGGCCCCAGG
>k141_436839 flag=0 multi=1.0000 len=205
ATGAAATCACGATGTTTTTCTGATTCTACGAGTTAGGGAGAACATGAATCATCAGCTCTTTTTTAAATCTGGTGTTTGTCTGAGCCGGGAACCTCAGTTCTCAAAGGGCAGTTTTGCCATTGCGAGAATAGGCCATTTGAGCAATTGCGGTAATAGGCCGTTTCGGCCAAATTTCTTCTTGGTGTCACTCTTCAGGAAAAGAGAG
>k141_624048 flag=1 multi=3.0000 len=318
GTGCATAATCGCGGTATGGTGAAGGCCCGCTTCGACTTTTAGCGCCAACGCCAGCGCGCTATCAAAATCGCTGACTTTCACAATGGGCAGCATGGGCATCAGTTGTTCACACGTGACCCACGGATCTTCGGCATTCACCACCGCGATGAGCAGGCGAGGCGTTTTTGCCGGTGTTGCGATGTCTGATGCTTCCAGTAGCGTCGCCGGGCTCTTACCCACCAGTTTTTTATTCGCATGACCATCCTGTAGACAGACGGTACGTAATTTATCGGTGTCCGACGGGCTGAGAAGCAGCGCGCCAAACGCTTGCATCTGCTG
>k141_395237 flag=1 multi=4.0000 len=344
GCATACAATGGTGAGACTATGGTGGATCGACTAGATTGGGACAATGGTTTACTCGAAGGAACGGAAGTTTTAGGGCTGTTGAACTCGGCTCAAATTGTAGATATTCCATTTAAACCAAATGGACAATACGACCGAATTTCGATTGGACTGAAAAGCTTAATCCATGCGGATGTACTTTCGGCTATTGAAATCTACAAAGTAGAACGCGTATGTGATCTAATAGGATCTAACCAAAATTTAGTGTCGTGGAAGTCGTACAAAGTAAATGACGATGCTACTGTTACTTCGGTTTCAGGTGGTGAACAAGTGGAATATACCATCCATGTGAAAAATATAGGAACCAC
```

Say i want the sequence identified as `>k141_436839`, such that the output file is:

```
>k141_436839 flag=0 multi=1.0000 len=205
ATGAAATCACGATGTTTTTCTGATTCTACGAGTTAGGGAGAACATGAATCATCAGCTCTTTTTTAAATCTGGTGTTTGTCTGAGCCGGGAACCTCAGTTCTCAAAGGGCAGTTTTGCCATTGCGAGAATAGGCCATTTGAGCAATTGCGGTAATAGGCCGTTTCGGCCAAATTTCTTCTTGGTGTCACTCTTCAGGAAAAGAGAG
```

A post on a similar question suggests this but it didn't work: `sed -n -e '/^>k141_436839 $/,/^>$/{ /^>$/d; p; }'`

The length `len=` is also important. Here is one answer:

```
 awk '/^>/{f=/>k141_436839 flag=0 multi=1.0000 len=205/} f' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks straightforward:

```
sed -n '/^>k141_436839 /{N;p;}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and the code above and there are actually multiple sequences under the same ID but differentiated by the length "len="

Comment: @AGE: And...? My solution will print all sequences under that ID. Do you want something different?

Comment: What I meant is that the length (len=) should also be an identifier, since multiple sequences are under the ID >k141_436839 but only one with that identifier and of length 205. I tried  `sed -n '/^>k141_53828 flag=1 multi=46.2981 len=36164 /{N;p;}'` but that, not surprisingly, doesn't work.

Comment: @AGE: Did you try `sed -n '/^>k141_436839 .*len=205/{N;p;}'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^>/{f=/>k141_436839 /} f' file
>k141_436839 flag=0 multi=1.0000 len=205
ATGAAATCACGATGTTTTTCTGATTCTACGAGTTAGGGAGAACATGAATCATCAGCTCTTTTTTAAATCTGGTGTTTGTCTGAGCCGGGAACCTCAGTTCTCAAAGGGCAGTTTTGCCATTGCGAGAATAGGCCATTTGAGCAATTGCGGTAATAGGCCGTTTCGGCCAAATTTCTTCTTGGTGTCACTCTTCAGGAAAAGAGAG
```

Note that the above will print the whole record no matter how many lines there are between each `>` line and it will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: To be more specific, assume you don't know where it is located (i.e. that it is the third sequence) and that there are many sequences. All that is known is >k141_436839

Comment: Done to reflect what I really want.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v value=">k141_436839" '/^>/{found=""} $1==value{print;found=1;next} found{print}' Input_file
```

I have created a variable named `value` here which has the value of matching string, so you could change it as per your need and code will look for that string then.

Comment: @AGE, Could you please try this solution once too and let me know then?

Comment: `{print;found=1;next} found{print}` = `{found=1} found` and as a whole `/^>/{found=""} $1==value{print;found=1;next} found{print}` = `/^>/{found=($1==value)} found`

Answer (score 1):

if the data in `d` file, tried on gnu bash and sed,
either on console or put into a bash script file:

```
id=k141_436839    
sed -En "/^>$id/{N;p;q}" d
```

add -i option to have the result back to data `d`